# Obtaining the color of button/layout/element

Tags: java, android, testing, background-color, uicolor

Similiar questions were very old so I post a new one.
I need to get the color of the layout and I tried previous responses, but i. e.:

- I can't invoke the findViewById method, it gets colored in red in my IDE,
- I don't have a particular ID for a layout, only index; id's are the same for similar items in the app,
- I need to verify the colors of background for search results which are different for specific searches,
- can't use getCssValue since I get an error that method has not been implemented yet.

How can I deal with that?

Screenshot from the app, need to verify only the color of search result (example titled 'D41').
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqvwQ.png

Sample code of a test, which doesn't work with getCssValue:

`@Test public void searchOperatorSign01() { 
driver.findElementById("search_button").click(); driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='‌​OperatorsWithSigns1'‌​]").click(); driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index=‌​'2']").sendKeys("D41‌​"); driver.findElementById("search_mask").click();
String cssVal = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[@‌​index='0']").getCssV‌​alue("background-col‌​or")`

Comment: I don't know why you want to the color of your item but to display item you must know it. So you should use the values inside your item instead of using the display to retrieve some data.

Comment: Please paste actual code, not a screenshot. The idea is that SO members can copy/paste it; i.e. no-one is going to write it down manually character by character.

Comment: I'm testing an app, not writing it.
Code of the test looks like this.
`@Test
    public void searchOperatorSign01() {
        driver.findElementById("search_button").click();  
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='OperatorsWithSigns1']").click();  
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.EditText[@index='2']").sendKeys("D41");  
        driver.findElementById("search_mask").click();  
        String cssVal = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='0']").getCssValue("background-color")
`

Comment: damn i dunno how to comment properly xD

Comment: Just edit your first post with that code